# Using SwiperJS, how to keyboard tab through active slide only

Tags: javascript, keyboard, accessibility, focus, swiper.js

Accessibility has become a big initiative with our site and one of the issues I'm trying to resolve is how to configure our slider, which typically includes three slides, so that when a user navigates through our page using a keyboard for navigation, once they get to the slides, the tabbing only goes through the active slide. Currently, once they get to the [SwiperJS](https://swiperjs.com) slides, the focus lands on a slide that isn't in view and the user loses their place on the site.

The ideal experience after tabbing into the visible (active) slide would be this. For example, we'll say this slide has two links. One is a link for "More details", the other is a CTA button that reads, "Shop now".

1. User lands on the first focusable link on the slide, "More details".
2. Clicking "tab" takes the user to the "Shop now" CTA button.
3. Clicking "tab" takes the user to the "Previous" button on the left side of the slide.
4. Clicking "tab" takes the user to the "Next" button on the right side of the slide.
5. Clicking "tab" takes the user to the bullet along the bottom that corresponds to this slide. As you continue to click "tab" it goes through the other navigation bullets.
6. Clicking "tab" one last time while in the slide takes the user out of the slides where the user can continue navigation through the rest of the page.

Here's what we have currently for the options in our custom JS. How can I configure the SwiperJS as requested?

```
    options = {
        init: false,
        a11y: true,
        watchOverflow: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: null,
            prevEl: null,
            hideOnClick: true
        },
        pagination: {
            el: null,
            clickable: true
        },
        loop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        mousewheel: true,
    },
```

Comment: Please try to [Create a Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that allows us to analyse the issue.

Comment: Fixing accessibility issues via a component’s API is almost never feasible. It has to be considered when choosing the libraries. Swiper don’t even mention accessibility on their feature list, and on their demo it’s even impossible to switch slides by means of keyboard. If the Slider does not hide invisible slides from assistive technology or keyboard focus, that is a very deep issue that you cannot fix. By working around the focus issue, you’ll probably simply fall stumble over the next a11y issue.